# CSS - absolutely positioned child doesn't resize parent

Tags: css

I have a page with an absolutely positioned menu (because it needs to be in a certain place, never mind what's under it). How do I make that page resize to contain the menu?
I've made an [example of the problem on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CNfKn/), although no Javascript is used and I'd prefer not to use it.

What, I need to include the code? Fine... nicer example on jsFiddle

```
#container {float: left; width: 500px;}
#content {float: right; width: 300px; height: 100px;}
#menu {position: absolute; width: 100px; height: 350px;}
```

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">Content</div>
    <div id="menu">Menu</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using absolute positioning on the menu, it doesn't affect the height of the parent container.

Use `min-height` on the `#container` like this:

```
#container {
    background: #ff00ff;
    float: left;
    width: 500px;
    padding: 10px;
    min-height: 350px;
}
```

Comment: I don't know how tall the menu will be. It could be 1600px tall

Comment: So there is no way for an absolutely positioned child element to change the height of the container? I have to use js?

Comment: Yep. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085931/how-to-set-height-of-parent-of-absolutely-positioned-element-to-grow-shrink-with?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5359574/resize-parent-div-to-match-absolutly-positioned-child-div-height?rq=1

Comment: The absolute position takes an element out of the normal element flow, so it does not affect the size or shape of its parent. Only `relative` or `static` are in the normal flow. Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009798/css-position-absolute-document-flow

Comment: You should really reconsider this layout using floats. If the menu floats left and you add a "clear:both" element, everything works out to your spec. See http://jsfiddle.net/CNfKn/4/

Comment: Yeah, but how do I put something under the menu then? (meaning depth-wise)

Comment: It takes a little rearranging but you can do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/CNfKn/5/ Is that what you mean? It does funny things to the text flow, but it can be worked with using padding on the content element. http://jsfiddle.net/CNfKn/6/

Comment: @L84 [zindex](http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Overlapping_And_ZIndex) can be used to effect what "depth" elements appear at regardless of source order.